# How would I find the answer to X% of X in PHP?

Tags: php, math, numbers

I have two variables:

```
$percent = '3.5'; //this is the percentage
$order = 400;
//so how would i get $percent of $order?
```

Now in PHP how would I find out what 3.5% of 400 is (I know its 14) - but would like to know how to calculate it directly in PHP using those two variables above.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: Just a comment though, $percent shouldn't be in quotes, as it's a number and not a string :)

Comment: @jValdron I actually tried that first but kept throwing a PHP error...i tried investigating and seemed like the . (period) within the number was causing the problem (as a whole number without quotes parsed fine error-free), so I eventually resorted to enclosing it within single quotes. FYI - that was tested via XAMPP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Percent" just means "per 100" or "over 100" or "/ 100"

```
$percentOfOrder = $order * ($percent / 100);
```

Comment: Damn how I regret truanting those maths lessons :/

Answer (score 2):

You could make a `percentOf` function:

```
function percentOf($number, $percent){
    return $number * ($percent / 100);
}

//then:
echo percentOf($order, $percent);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/a6BgEEs2