# Deducting a x% in PHP

Tags: php

Here's an example of what i'm trying to do. Any help on best practice here would be very helpful!

```
<?php 

$fullprice = "5990";

$discount = "30"; // This is 30 percentage

echo = $fullprice - $discount; // Here i need to deduct 30% from the fullprice ?

?>
```

Comment: echo $finalPrice = $fullprice -( $discount*$fullprice/100);

Comment: This may help: [How would I find the answer to X% of X in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316558/how-would-i-find-the-answer-to-x-of-x-in-php)

Comment: Basic math....?

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $fullprice * ((100 - $discount) / 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$fullprice = 5990;

$discount = 30; // This is 30 percentage

echo $fullprice * ((100 - $discount) / 100);
```

Comment: `echo = ...` = Syntax error :)

Comment: @Jack :  ahhh .. copy / paste without checking. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo $fullprice * (1 - $discount/100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Idiot proof discount price calculation:

```
$fullPrice * (100 - max(0, min(100, $discount))) / 100;
```

It squashes the discount percentage between 0 and 100 inclusive.